# How Web To Lead Works Under the hood

Tags: apex, visualforce, leads, web2lead

Salesforce generates HTML for web to lead setup. Which eventually creates lead directly in our org.
What I want to know is that how actually it works, I assume it uses rest services to create lead, if so how it do authentication and all other handling.
I couldn't find any documentation for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look on the HTML form generated using Web-to-Lead, you will notice as below:

```
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
```

This signifies that its a POST request made to a [servlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafe.html) hosted on Salesforce servers which does not need any authentication (in this case). So from the Web, you just post the request to this servlet. There is **no** REST or SOAP API call that is made here.

The incoming request is then captured and translated to a Lead record in Salesforce, where the record owner is pre-defined when you first enabled the Web-to-Lead in Salesforce. So irrespective of from where the web form was submitted, the leads created will always have the owner as defined in your settings.

[image]